# IP board not working on my new vps

Tags: centos5, php5

my invision power board is not working on my new vps but it working on my old hosting provider's server.

ERROR:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/forumfus/public_html/index.php:2) in /home/forumfus/public_html/dontadminhack/sources/classes/output/formats/html/htmlOutput.php on line 223

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/forumfus/public_html/index.php:2) in /home/forumfus/public_html/dontadminhack/sources/classes/output/formats/html/htmlOutput.php on line 248

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/forumfus/public_html/index.php:2) in /home/forumfus/public_html/dontadminhack/sources/classes/output/formats/html/htmlOutput.php on line 266

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/forumfus/public_html/index.php:2) in /home/forumfus/public_html/dontadminhack/sources/classes/output/formats/html/htmlOutput.php on line 268

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/forumfus/public_html/index.php:2) in /home/forumfus/public_html/dontadminhack/sources/classes/output/formats/html/htmlOutput.php on line 276
```

i have check ipb requirement using ipb,s check_requirements.php file that in download form there support forum.
Forum URL:
http://srv1.offshoreracks.net/~forumfus/

check requirement URL:

http://srv1.offshoreracks.net/~forumfus/check_requirements.php

in ipb check requirement every thing is passed.

but ipb is not working my new vps 
please help me i think it needs something installed on new server.

Comment: What do the first few lines of /home/forumfus/public_html/index.php look like?

Comment: entire index.php look like this

Comment: entire index.php look like this image                           http://s12.postimage.org/3nfwaxbml/ipb.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the blank line at the top of index.php.

The opening php tag should be at the very start of the first line.
That blank line is being output to the browser, which is causing the web server to send HTTP headers. When the IPB code tries to send HTTP headers, they've already been sent, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your FTP client trashed your files when you uploaded them. Be sure to set it to ASCII mode when uploading, or use SFTP. Or best of all, work directly on the server.